# ng-include not working in IE

Tags: angularjs

I have developed a webpage using AngularJS and have tested it with Google Chrome during development. Everythinh works fine as it should in Chrome but now I've also tested it in Internet Explorer 9 and there I have a big problem. I have a ng-repeat that show persons with different html according to a category they belong to. To be able to show different lay-outs per person I use the following code:

Html-code

```
<ul class="listview image" >
    <ng:include src="getIncludeFile(profile)" data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles"></ng:include>
</ul>
```

Javascript

```
$scope.getIncludeFile = function(profile) {
        switch (profile.Age) {
            case "Child":
                return 'Child.html'; break;
            case "Elder":
                return 'Elder.html'; break;
            default:
                return 'Adult.html';
        }
    }
```

I have read the angular docs and I have the following at the top of my main html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:ng="http://angularjs.org" class="ng-app:app" id="ng-app" lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-controller="appController">
```

It doesn't really matter what I put in the template, it will never show in IE. The correct amount of ng-includes appear in the DOM so I don't think the problem is the ng-repeat. I haven't found any similar problems on the internet so I'm asking you if anybody knows what could be wrong?

Comment: Ok, so I managed to make it work using ng-switch instead of ng-include but I would love to discuss this further to find a solution. I prefer to use the ng-include.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing it to this:

```
<div ng-include="getIncludeFile(profile)" data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles"></div>
```

You are trying to use tags that modern browsers recognize, but IE9 and below don't, especially using colons in the tag name.
If you want to play it REALLY safe use the `data-` prefix in front of everything.  You can also use the HTML5 Shiv in a conditional HTML statement for IE9 and below to continue playing it safe.

Comment: I had already tried it that way, but it makes no difference. I will only be supporting IE9 en 10 and I thought the issue you mention was only IE8 and earlier?

Answer (score 0):

Here is my trial of solving your issue..

editable version..
http://plnkr.co/edit/4PmbuLYYFLNwi6mRFaRP

Open it in windowed mode and then use url in IE9 to do a test run.

Hope this helps..

Comment: The first link isn't working and there's not much code in the 2nd one. Can you check if the urls are correct? Thank you

Comment: In Firefox it works perfectly but in IE I get an error.
User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)
Timestamp: Tue, 18 Jun 2013 06:21:19 UTC  

Message: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!
Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: ...some code...  
Line: 2  
Char: 12426  
Code: 0  
URI: http://plnkr.co/js/apps/editor-0.6.20.js

Answer (score 0):

For IE8+
Keep the ng-include in a separate div like:

```
<ul class="listview image" >
    <div data-ng-repeat="profile in profiles">
        <ng:include src="getIncludeFile(profile)"></ng:include>
    </div>      
</ul>
```

You can get it working in IE7 by disabling $sce as ngInclude uses $sce.